# Error when reverse url with multiple arguments - Django

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing, tdd

I'm writing a test for an url, problem is it fails when I try to pass multiple arguments, here is some code:

```
#test_urls.py
from django.test import SimpleTestCase
from django.urls import reverse, resolve
from cardiotesting.views import *

class TestUrls(SimpleTestCase):
    def test_new_cardio(id_patient, protocol):
        id_patient = '05'
        protocol = 'fox'
        url = reverse('new_cardio_testing', args=[id_patient, protocol])
        print(resolve(url))
```

```
#urls.py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('new/<str:id_patient>', views.new_cardio_testing, name='new_cardio_testing'),
]
```

```
#views.py
def new_cardio_testing(id_patient, protocol):
    pass
```

When I run the test it returns:

```
.E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_new_cardio_testing (cardiotesting.tests.test_urls.TestUrls)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError: TestUrls.test_new_cardio_testing() missing 1 required positional argument: 'protocol'
```

But when there is only one argument the test succeeds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

test methods just take one parameter and that is *self*, so your test class must be something like this:

```
class TestUrls(SimpleTestCase):
    def test_new_cardio(self):
        id_patient = '05'
        protocol = 'fox'
        url = reverse('new_cardio_testing', args=[id_patient, protocol])
        print(resolve(url))
```

Answer (score 4):

Your urlpatterns seem unfit to accept this format.
Try the following:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('new/<str:id_patient>/<str:protocol>/', views.new_cardio_testing, name='new_cardio_testing'),
    # Django loves it's trailing slashes.
]
```